# Lead Conversion with existing account and avoid duplicate contact in that account

Tags: lead-conversion

In Lead Conversion with existing account if created contact name is same as existing contact in account then not need to create account.

In my Case i take query to fetch list of contact present in existing account and compare if new contact name and existing accont contact name is not same then create an account else not. and also need to create corresponding owner.

problem is m unable to restrict duplicate contact while conversion

code:

```
trigger LeadConversionTrigger on Lead (before update) {

    map<Id, Lead> mapNewLead = trigger.newMap; 
    System.debug(mapNewLead);
    List<Contact> otherContact = new List<Contact>();   
    List <Owner__c> ownerList=new List<Owner__c>();
    Integer Flag=0;
    for(Lead objLead: mapNewLead.values()) 
    { 
        System.debug(objLead);
        if (objLead.IsConverted == true ) 
        { 
            List<Contact> con=new List<Contact>([Select id, Name,LastName From Contact Where Account.Id=:objLead.convertedAccountId]);
            System.debug(con);
            for(Contact cnt :con)
            {
                if(cnt.LastName !=objLead.Owner_2_Name__c )
                {
                    System.debug(cnt.LastName);
                    System.debug(objLead.Owner_2_Name__c);
                    Flag ++;
                }
            }
            System.debug(Flag);
            if(con.size() == Flag)
            {
                System.debug(con.size());
                otherContact.add(new contact(LastName = objLead.Owner_2_Name__c,
                                             Phone = objLead.Owner_2_Phone__c, 
                                             Email = objLead.Owner_2_Email_Address__c,
                                             Owner_1_City__c =objLead.Owner_2_City__c, 
                                             Birthdate =objLead.Owner_2_DOB__c,
                                             Owner1_Home_Address__c=objLead.Owner_2_Home_Address__c,
                                             Title=objLead.Owner_2_Job_Title__c, 
                                             Social_Security_Number__c=objLead.Owner_2_SSN__c,
                                             Owner_1_State__c=objLead.Owner_2_State__c,
                                             Owner_1_Zip__c=objLead.Owner_2_Zip__c,
                                             AccountId =objLead.convertedAccountId));
            }

        }
        if(otherContact==Null)
            insert otherContact;
        System.debug(otherContact);

        Map<Id, Contact> con = new Map<Id, Contact>(otherContact);
System.debug(con);        
List<Contact> cntct=[Select Id,LastName From Contact where Id IN:con.keySet()];
System.debug(cntct);

         if (objLead.IsConverted == true )
{
ownerList.add(new Owner__c( Contact__c=cntct[0].Id,
Account__c=objLead.Account__c,
Ownership__c=objLead.Owner_1__c));

ownerList.add(new Owner__c(Contact__c=cntct[0].Id,
Account__c=objLead.Account__c,
Ownership__c=objLead.Owner_2__c));
}
insert ownerList;

    }        
}
```

Comment: You can merge if a duplicate contact is created.

Comment: Can be upper/lower case issue. Check buy using toLowerCase() method to convert both contact and lead name to lowercase and then try comparison.